# Microsoft Mediaroom Buttonclick event

Tags: asp.net

iam having a doubt regarding the TVButton control of mediaroom.there are events and actions which comes with mediaroom presentation framework.how can i call my own event handler for tvbutton in my code. 
onButtonClick="btnlogin_ButtonClick" is not working. if i write my custom code for void btnlogin_ButtonClick(object sender,EventArgs e){ }

onButtonClick is not firing!
 Sample code of mediaroom!

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SubmitAction_01_Designer.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="TVPage_TVPage_Submit" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="TVControls" Namespace="Microsoft.TV.TVControls" TagPrefix="mrml" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="TVControls" Namespace="Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Actions" TagPrefix="mrml" %>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<mrml:TVPage ID="TVPage1" runat="server" Style="position: absolute;">
    <mrml:TVPanel ID="TVPanel2" runat="server" Background="image(file:/BG_Masthead.png)"
        Style="z-index: 102; left: 0px; width: 632px; position: absolute; top: 0px; height: 99px">
        <mrml:TVImage ID="TVImage2" runat="server" Style="left: 16px; width: 260px; position: absolute;
            top: 23px; height: 80px" Url="file:///Brand_Service_Menu.png">
        </mrml:TVImage>
        <mrml:TVLabel ID="TVLabel3" runat="server" Background="@Transparent" Foreground="@TextHeader"
            HorizontalAlign="right" VerticalAlign="bottom" Padding="rect(0,0,0,0)" Style="left: 265px;
            width: 331px; position: absolute; top: 13px; height: 69px" Text="SubmitAction - Designer"
            Wrap="false">
        </mrml:TVLabel>
    </mrml:TVPanel>
    <mrml:TVText ID="TVText1" runat="server" Style="position: absolute; top: 137px; left: 347px;"
        MaxChars="100">
    </mrml:TVText>
    <mrml:TVButton ID="TVButton1" runat="server" Style="position: absolute; top: 197px;
        left: 352px;" OnClick="SubmitAction0" Text="Click To submit">
    </mrml:TVButton>
    <mrml:TVActions ID="TVActions1" runat="server" Actions-Capacity="4">
        <mrml:SubmitAction Gadgets="TVText1" Method="Get" Name="SubmitAction0" Target=""
            Url="SubmitAction_02_Designer.aspx" X="5" Y="5" />
    </mrml:TVActions>
    <mrml:TVLabel ID="TVLabel4" runat="server" Style="position: absolute; top: 137px;
        left: 67px; height: 158px; width: 246px;" Text="Enter some text in TVText and click on TVButton to submit the TVpage. When the TVPage is submitted,
the control goes to the next page where you can see the text entered in the previous page.">
    </mrml:TVLabel>
</mrml:TVPage>
</form>
```

So here we can only give  OnClick="SubmitAction0".  The above sample is the source view

The code behind sample:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Actions;
using Microsoft.TV.TVControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*        <mrml:MoveAction Height="40" Left="270" Name="MoveAction0" Target="txtMove" 
            Top="138" Width="100" X="117" Y="117" />
        <mrml:ShowAction Name="ShowAction0" Targets="lblShow" X="89" Y="89" />
        <mrml:SetAction Name="SetAction0" PropertyName="value" PropertyValue="Set" 
            Target="txtSet" X="61" Y="61" />
        <mrml:HideAction Name="HideAction0" Targets="lblHide" X="5" Y="5" />
        <mrml:KeyAction Key="1" Name="KeyAction0" Target="txtKey" X="33" Y="33" />
        <mrml:FocusAction Name="FocusAction0" Target="btnFocus" X="229" Y="100" />*/

        MoveAction objMove = new MoveAction("MoveAction0", "txtMove", 270, 138, 100, 40);
        TVActions1.Actions.Add(objMove);
        ShowAction objShow = new ShowAction("ShowAction0", "lblShow");
        TVActions1.Actions.Add(objShow);
        SetAction objSet = new SetAction("SetAction0", "txtSet", "value", "Set");
        TVActions1.Actions.Add(objSet);
        HideAction objHide = new HideAction("HideAction0", "lblHide");
        TVActions1.Actions.Add(objHide);
        KeyAction objKey = new KeyAction("KeyAction0", "txtKey", "1");
        TVActions1.Actions.Add(objKey);
        FocusAction objFocus = new FocusAction("FocusAction0", "btnFocus");
        TVActions1.Actions.Add(objFocus);

        TVButton1.OnClick = new Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Events.ClickEvent("ShowAction0");
        TVButton2.OnClick = new Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Events.ClickEvent("HideAction0");
        TVButton3.OnClick = new Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Events.ClickEvent("SetAction0");
        TVButton4.OnClick = new Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Events.ClickEvent("KeyAction0");
        TVButton5.OnClick = new Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Events.ClickEvent("FocusAction0");
        TVButton6.OnClick = new Microsoft.TV.TVControls.Events.ClickEvent("MoveAction0");

        //Following lines are for displaying the file name
        /*<mrml:TVLabel ID="lblFileName" runat="server" 
                style="position: absolute; top: 69px; left: 9px; width: 241px;" Text="TVLabel">
            </mrml:TVLabel>*/
        TVLabel lblFileName = new TVLabel();
        lblFileName.ID = "lblFileName";
        lblFileName.Left = 40;
        lblFileName.Top = 70;
        lblFileName.Width = 500;
        lblFileName.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath;
        lblFileName.IsVisible = true;
        TVPage1.Controls.Add(lblFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that the post is old, but did you found a solution? Any other idea how to call some method from aspx (javascript) to cs?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with OnClick not OnButtonClick

```
OnClick="btnlogin_ButtonClick"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually i tried that also..it works absolutely fine in asp.net...but in mediaroom presentation framework(MPF) which is used for developing applications for set-top box for IPTV  it is not working.here we have events which call only actions.But iam not able to call my own action or eventhandler.plz help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need some information about this, but
in your specific case to call a page by the button click the Href seems to work better like this example

```
<mrml:TVButton ID="TVButton7" runat="server" Background="argb(211,0,79,194)" 
         Href="~/Menu%20principal/Menu.aspx" IsVisible="False" 
         style="position: absolute; top: 433px; left: 224px;" Text="Back to Menu">
</mrml:TVButton>
```

And then use the Page_Load event of the page to do what you want.